# Firebase Authentication setting users to deactive without using currentuser

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

I am making an admin tool page to allow admins to change users email for when they change or set their account to deactivate so they can not access the site anymore. Everything I have looked at seems to be using 'CurrentUser' but this will not work due to the fact they will be logged in as themselves which is marked as Admin level so they have access to the tool. So is there any way to change a users email for authentication without logging in as them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the Firebase Authentication client-side SDKs had an API that allowed you to change the email address of anyone but yourself that'd be a major security risk.

This is the reason an API to [update any user by their UID](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-users#update_a_user) only exists in the Admin SDK, which can only be run on a trusted environment as it requires full administrative access to your project.

If you want to expose this functionality to specific users of your app, you'll have to wrap the relevant call of the Admin SDK into a custom endpoint that you then call from the app. Just make sure to check that the user is authorized, before changing some other user's account.